# Unable to install Android apk from AppCenter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have an ant script that builds&deploy a MFP app for android (wlapp and apk). I also upload the app to AppCenter.

The problem is that I cannot install (on a device - Huawei P6) the apk from the AppCenter using the AppCenter app - it downloads the app but the installation is not successful. The uploaded app is not signed.

Running the Android app from the MFP Studio works fine.

What steps do I have to perform in order to make the installation from AppCenter app work? Where can I see the logs from AppCenter?

Thanks!

Ant target:

```
    <target name="build-android-windows" if="isWindows" description="Build the Android .apk" depends="">
    <!-- These must be set in your local.properties file in the root of the android project.
         This is sensitive information and is not checked into the repository
    <fail unless="android.store" message="Property android.store missing" />
    <fail unless="android.alias" message="Property android.alias missing" />
    <fail unless="android.store.password" message="Property android.store.password missing" />
    <fail unless="android.alias.password" message="Property android.alias.password missing" />
    -->
    <!-- use android.release_target if defined, otherwise default to 'release' -->
    <property name="android.release_target" value="release"/>

    <!-- call the project's build.xml to clean -->
    <ant antfile="${src.dir}/apps/${curBrand}/android/native/build.xml" inheritAll="false" useNativeBasedir="true" target="clean"/>

    <!-- call the project's build.xml to make a build -->
    <ant antfile="${src.dir}/apps/${curBrand}/android/native/build.xml" inheritAll="false" useNativeBasedir="true" target="${android.release_target}" />
    <!-- copy the file to build.dir -->
    <copy file="${src.dir}/apps/${curBrand}/android/native/bin/${curBrand}-${android.release_target}-unsigned.apk" tofile="${build.dir}/android/${build.apk}" overwrite="true" failonerror="true"/>

</target>
```

Comment: Did you try signing your apk (try building it without ant for a moment) and then upload this apk to appcenter and try to install. Does it pass?

Comment: Have you checked the security settings on the device ? Install from sources other than Playstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vivin suggested in the comments, the AppCenter is *not* Google Play meaning it is not a "trusted source" at least from the device's perspective, thus you may need indeed to enable that option in Android's options.

The second option is as I mentioned - to sign the .apk. When you build directly from Eclipse it uses debug signing by default and goes straight into the device.

Comment: That security setting is enabled.

Comment: After signing the APK, the installation worked. Thanks!